# Exchange Attributes to create Distribution List

Tags: php, exchange-2010, exchange

I am currently working on a project regarding the
creation of distribution lists through a web interface. I have chosen to
use PHP for this as it is a language with which I am well versed.

I know how to add an LDAP account in PHP, but my issue is that I am
unsure of which AD attributes are required in order to turn a group into
a distribution list. I know I can use powershell, but I would prefer to
do this in a way with which I am familiar.

The code I am using to compile the distribution list attributes are as follows:

```
$attDist = array(
"managedBy"                 =>  $secGroupDn,
"groupType"                 =>  "8",            // This number denotes a universal distribution group
"cn"                        =>  $dlName,
"samaccountname"            =>  $dlName,
"displayname"               =>  $dlName,
"objectClass"               =>  "Group",
"legacyexchangeDN"          =>  "/o=First Organization/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=". substr($dlName, 0, 4) . time(),
"proxyaddresses"            =>  array("SMTP:". $dlName ."@testdomain.local"),
"showinaddressbook"         =>  array(
    "CN=Groups(VLV),CN=All System Address Lists,CN=Address Lists Container,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=testdomain,DC=local",
    "CN=All Groups(VLV),CN=All System Address Lists,CN=Address Lists Container,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=testdomain,DC=local",
    "CN=All Recipients(VLV),CN=All System Address Lists,CN=Address Lists Container,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=testdomain,DC=local",
    "CN=Default Global Address List,CN=All Global Address Lists,CN=Address Lists Container,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=testdomain,DC=local",
    "CN=All Groups,CN=All Address Lists,CN=Address Lists Container,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=testdomain,DC=local",
),
"mail"                      =>  $dlName . "@testdomain.local",
"msexchversion"             =>  "44220983382016",
"msexcharbitrationmailbox"  =>  "CN=SystemMailbox{1f05a927-ccef-4207-91c0-7550cb8790db},CN=Users,DC=testdomain,DC=local",
"msexchrequireauthtosendto" =>  "TRUE",
"mailnickname"              =>  $dlName,
"msexchpoliciesincluded"    =>  array(
    "bcdf8b57-a774-4d82-980a-68f7f7d9f54d",
    "{26491cfc-9e50-4857-861b-0cb8df22b5d7}",
),
"msexchrecipientdisplaytype" => "1",
"description"       =>  "Managed by: Someone",
"info"              =>  "Created by ". $creatorName ." on ". date("d/M/Y") .". CA ". $caTicket .". Managed by: TBD",
```

);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't specifically address this with PHP, but I can tell you that I create universal mail enabled security group / DL with LDAP via perl with this call:

```
$res = $ldap->add(
    dn   => $dn,
    attr => [
        sAMAccountName       => $group,
        name                 => $group,
        displayName          => $dname,
        displayNamePrintable => $pdname,
        objectclass          => [ 'top', 'group' ],
        groupType            => -2147483640
    ]
);
```

You'll then want to add attributes for 'mail', 'mailNickname', 'proxyAddresses', and depending on your environment, you may need to populate a 'legacyExchangeDN'.

Comment: Thanks. I have the basic attributes to create the group, but the issue is specifically with the following attributes (I have created a DL through EMC and noted the attributes from adsiedit):
showInAddressBook
mxExchArbitrationMailbox
msExchPoliciesIncluded
legacyExchangeDN

These attributes get created automatically when done through the EMC, and work fine when I use these same attributes for the DL created in PHP, and it doesn't seem to cause an issue, but I am worried it may cause problems outside the test environment. Code added to main post.

I've added the array which I'm currently using.

Comment: showInAddressBook is optional - if you want it to show up in the GAL. I populate legacyExchangeDN with just a unique value. I tend to use something matching the Exchange Org Structure followed by /cn=Recipients/ou=MyDLLocation/cn=$group. I don't believe the others are required for it to function - at least I don't populate them. Only time we've seen issues is with certain characters in the displayNamePrintable (DOES NOT LIKE & and _ w/ newer exchange). Doesn't cause an issue, but other MS tools don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the proper API? Exchange Web Services (EWS) is well-documented and should support whatever you want to do.

[EWS-Distributionlist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa566353%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx)